# Post images, videos, Gallery/Album to Instagram using Instagram Developer API

Tags: php, image, video, gallery, instagram-api

I am using a PHP application and i want to post Images, Videos, Image/Video Gallery programatically using Instagram API.

how can i accomplish the same using https://www.instagram.com/developer/ ?

Comment: you cannot post images using API, it is not supported, u have to use Instagram app

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i found this  PHP API https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API where they have examples of posting media to instagram account programatically.

Comment: But they are making a CURL request to end points on https://i.instagram.com and i could not find this API anywhere.

Comment: thats private undocumented API that Instagram uses, it may change anytime...

Comment: It seems they are using this API https://instagram.api-docs.io/

Comment: those are private APIs

Comment: So can you please let me know if you have any idea about this..is it safe to use these libraries, are these libraries scalable, secure ?

Comment: some risks you take are: it may stop working anytime, the user you are using to authenticate may get blocked, IP may get blocked

Comment: yes IP getting blocked issue  i am already facing. can you please suggest any solution to this IP block issue ?

Comment: Can you please suggest me some API or way to authenticate and post images and videos to Instagram programmatically?

Comment: u cannot, Instagram does not allow that legally, post manually using app

Comment: Then how this site is doing it automated https://www.hopperhq.com/faq/ check question Is Hopper HQ in-line with Instagram's terms & conditions? if they are not using Instagram's Private API then any idea on how they are posting ?
Some people are suggesting using AWS services but i have no idea how to use AWs to accomplish the same which API to follow etc.

Comment: if they allow posting, they are using private API or automating android app to post

Comment: @krisrak can you please let me know how can we automate Instagram Android App and auto posting images videos from a source to different instagram accounts programatically ?

Comment: I dont know how they do it, its not a good idea to do it

Answer (score 1):

As of **June 29, 2020**, Instagram has official API by Facebook:

[Facebook Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/)

From the document above:

**Common Uses**

- getting and managing published photos, videos, and stories
- getting basic data about other Instagram Business users and Creators
- moderating comments and their replies
- measuring media and profile interaction
- discovering hashtagged media
- discovering @mentions

**Limitations**

- The API cannot access Instagram consumer accounts (i.e., non-Business or non-Creator Instagram accounts). If you are building an app for consumer users, use the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) instead.
- IGTV and Reels are not supported.
- ordering results is not supported
- all endpoints support cursor-based pagination, but the User Insights edge is the only endpoint that supports time-based pagination

For media (image, video) control, [IG Media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media) is the API:

*It seems that Instagram API only contains reading methods, and I haven't seen any ability to upload new video*

**IG Media** node allows you to:

- get metadata for individual media objects
- toggle comments on or off for individual media objects
- create comments on individual media objects
- get all child media objects in an album carousel
- get all comments for individual media objects
- get all insights for individual media objects